# max_element with lambda: how to compile?

Tags: c++, lambda, compiler-errors

I am learning some new C++ features and couldn't get the following code compiled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.push_back(1);
    numbers.push_back(5);
    numbers.push_back(3);
    numbers.push_back(9);
    numbers.push_back(10);
    numbers.push_back(8);

    std::cout << std::max_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [](int a, int b) { return a < b;}) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My gcc version:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The output when I try to compile:

```
$ g++ test_max_element.C 
test_max_element.C: In function ‘int main()’:
test_max_element.C:15:99: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
test_max_element.C:15:100: error: no matching function for call to ‘max_element(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, main()::<lambda(int, int)>)’
test_max_element.C:15:100: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:6229:5: note: template<class _FIter> _FIter std::max_element(_FIter, _FIter)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:6257:5: note: template<class _FIter, class _Compare> _FIter std::max_element(_FIter, _FIter, _Compare)
```

How can I fix this compilation error?

Comment: Upgrade your prehistoric version of `gcc` to `gcc 6.1.1`, and specify the `-std=c++1z` option to use the most recent version of C++. If you want to learn C++, you need to use a modern C++ compiler.

Comment: Also, the iterator won't in general have an overload that allows it to produce formatted output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 hints here.

## Syntax Error

```
std::cout << *std::max_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [](int a, int b) { return a < b;}) << std::endl;
```

*Note* the `*` operator. You need it because `max_element` returns an iterator, so in order to print the value you have to deference it.

## Obsolete Compiler Version

You're trying to using a modern C++ *features* with a too old compiler. I suggest you to upgrade it.
Anyway you can use the current compiler's version you have just add the flag `-std=c++0x` to the compiler command. But seeing from your question probabily the flag is enable by default.

Comment: The diagnostic that the OP presented suggests the exact opposite of what you claim in your last sentence.

Comment: Great, both hints work (although unclear why "-std=c++0x" has to be specified explicitly while compiler says enabled by default)! Thank you.

Comment: @user180574: "enabled by default" refers to the language feature or vendor extension, not to the `-std` flag.